CVXPY - Convex difference of quadratic forms
I have a sparse optimization problem of the form:
$$\min_x c^T x + \| D x\|^2_2 + \| V x\|^2_2  - \| W x\|^2_2$$
$D$ is diagonal and $V$, $W$ are non-square matrices. I know that:
$$Q = D^2 + V V^T - WW^T \succ 0$$
is positive definite. Ensuring convexity of the problem, but optimizing with dense matrix $Q$ is very slow.
Can we rewrite this problem so that it is accepted by a DCP solver like CVXPY, while keeping sparse structure of the problem ?
PS: problem also includes some constraints, so is non-quadratic

Unless you have some funny constraints on $x$ this is a linear problem that can be solved with the conjugate gradient solver:
$$\underbrace{(D^TD+V^TV-W^TW)}_{Q}x = -\frac{1}{2}c.$$
Implement the multiplication $Qx$ as $Qx = y+z-w$ where $y=D^TDx$, $z=V^TVx$, $w=W^TWx$, where each of those is implemented as a sparse multiplication, e.g., $w = W^Tw_0$ where $w_0 = Wx$.

It does include some constraints, I updated the description to reflect this

@ADNNNNNNNNNNN Can you write down the constraints of the problem?

Plenty!

linear constraints of the type  $$x^T v_i \leq f_i$$ as well some quadratic ones $$  x^T \Sigma_i x \leq q_i $$ and also some L1 like $$ | x |_1 \leq l $$

CVXPY handles all of that pretty easily. The goal now would be to add this new term $$ -| W x|_2^2 $$ on top of these

@ADNNNNNNNNNNN The only thing for cvxpy on matrix-free methods I found is this: https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/abs_ops.html
